# i trying to do load function using jquery in dreamweaver CS5 here it's not working

Tags: jquery, dreamweaver

I am trying to do the load function using dreamweaver CS5, but here I can't, I am getting this error message in chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///F:/suresh/HTML%20Files/google-adds-landing-pages/form.html.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }</style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Footer navigation:</b>
    <ol id="new-nav"></ol>
    <script> $("#new-nav").load("form.html");</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: then what will be better for me can you tell that

Comment: because i am new to webdevelopment

Comment: @emeraldcode.com - It's not appropriate to attack an OP based on the use of one type of software or another.

Comment: Looking at your error Suresh, it appears that you're trying to run your markup without a server. You'll need to configure a server and run your code/markup on that server, which can be on localhost.

Comment: I'm sorry Suresh. I didn't meant it in an attacking way. I would move away from tools like Dreamweaver. Its an illusion what it gives you. Start with a text editor and go to town on W3 Schools examples. You will be 1 million light years ahead doing it that way compared with dreamweaver. Trust me.

Comment: @emeraldcode.com You assume OP is using the drap and drop interface, when Dreamweaver actually has an excellent code view. There are better alternatives out there - sure - but Dreamweaver is far from the worst tool you could use, and many professional web developers still swear to Dreamweaver (using code view, of course).

Comment: @Nix you are correct. However, Suresh needs to step away from the temptation and stick with purity for a while to detox. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use WAMP, http://www.wampserver.com/en/
for your web development project and that would also solve your problem with the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: i download the file and installed but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Because I felt bad from my comment telling Suresh that Dreamweaver is cancer, I'll answer.

You are trying to access your file system and the browser does not like this as its violating its security policy. The problem with the question is you can't do anything about it as you are using Dreamweaver and it separates you from the real work that is much easier to do if you just take a little time to go through some examples on the web.

What you should do is go to kodingen.com which is my favorite website for doing quick prototypes. Open up another window for W3 Schools. Go to town on all the examples as much as you can absorb. This is assuming you want to understand things as Dreamweaver will only cloud your understanding. There are no shortcuts if you are really interested in being a web developer.